# How to call a PL/SQL procedure be name stored in table?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I have a table in Oracle DB which has a field where procedure names are stored. my goal is to create a menu procedure with a number parameter. So when i call it i want it to get procedure name by it's id(the number which was passed) from this table and call the procedure.
Hope i'm clear enough...

p.s I'm making a PL/SQL Server Page if it matters...

Comment: Why would you use PL/SQL Server Pages in 2011 when Apex has been around for several years?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is Dynamic PL/SQL:

```
procedure runproc (p_procname varchar2) is
begin
    execute immediate 'begin ' || p_procname || '; end;';
end;
```

Use bind variables for the parameters.  Since each procedure probably takes a different number of parameters you may need to use the [DBMS_SQL package](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_sql.htm#BABEDAHF).

Comment: Hmm.. dynamic pl/sql... isn't it a bit different from pure pl/sql? Do i need to install anything?

Comment: No you just create strings of PL/SQL and then use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE or DBMS_SQL to execute the strings dynamically.  Nothing to configure or install.

Comment: No, dynamic pl/sql is pretty much the same as regular sql.  The main difference is that it is not pre-compiled/pre-computed, so you will get worse performance from dynamic pl/sql than standard pl/sql.

Comment: My usual comment: be VERY sure that the use can't set the value of p_procname directly, only from your list. Don't pass it in a POST or GET, or you're opening yourself up for SQL Injection attacts. For example, what if they could replace your p_procname variable with "drop table CUSTOMERS;"?

Comment: Thank's for advise Jim. I POST an Id of procedure to select from table, so no worries there. The table only has names of procedures, which i allow ANONYMOUS user to execute.

Comment: and I'll add to use AUTHID CURRENT_USER instead of default (DEFINER) when using execute immediate.